# How to create a matrix with specific eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Is it possible to find a matrix with fixed eigenvalues and eigenvectors?
I've searched a lot, but I can't find an answer, so I'm asking.

Comment: This is really a math question.

Comment: It seems to be a simple linear algebra problem rather than a programming problem.

Comment: what do you mean fixed eigenvalues and eigenvectors? Given a system of equations the eigenvalues and eigenvectors are always fixed, they don't change depending on the weather.